# JS Async Function in QML

Tags: javascript, qml

I'm wondering if it is possible to use an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) in QML.
Like this:

```
async function additem(clientName){
    myListModel.append({name:clientName});
}
```

Instead of using this:

```
function additem(clientName){
    myListModel.append({name:clientName});
}
```

I've tried it and I get a syntax error: **Expected token:'`** and couldn't find any documentation about **QML supporting JavaScript "async function"**.

any idea why is that? or probably if there is any other way to do async in JS which can be used in QML?

**Note:** I want to append data to my **ListModel** and I want to see it as **its progress** and **I don't want whole application freezes** until whole data appended to the model.

Appreciate your time.

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't get that error in the browser, it will work just fine in the browser but not in QML. also, the error is `Expected token:'` like I'm missing **":"**

Comment: My apologies. I misunderstood what you were asking about

Comment: You can look at [this]( http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html#workerscript-threading-in-qml) but probably also [this]( https://github.com/benlau/quickpromise).

Comment: `WorkerScript` can easy do that

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for the comment, that is a good point but then WorkerScript is completely running separately and none of the QML libraries are imported! that raises another problem! :|

Comment: @folibis thanks for the reply, yeah good point, but that run separately, and none of QML libraries are imported, is there any possible way to import the libraries in javascript file?

Comment: Can you give an example, what you need for *QML libraries*?

Comment: @derM I'm developing a plugin for Substance Painter which is 3rd party application and it has it own JavaScript API that comes with QML, and I need that API which is "Painter 1.0" to access to Hard Drive and OS environment variables, knowing that pure Javascript doesn't provide such functionality.

Comment: Might you create a wrappe library, in which you define functions that allow you to pass the needed objects from QML to JS first?

Comment: You can import `QML` modules into `JS` file. Look at [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-imports.html#importing-a-qml-module-from-a-javascript-resource) article.

Comment: @folibis I tried it, and it throws syntax error, and then I look up the WorkerScript documentation, it mentions **Worker script can not use .import syntax.**  
Link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-workerscript.html

Comment: @derM It does work in normal JS file but throws syntax error for WorkerScript JS file, it does mention in the QML documentation. Link: doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-workerscript.html

Answer (score 1):

I answered a part of the expanded version of this question you posted to the Qt forums, but didn't address the async part.

From the example you give here, it's not clear why you're looking for async function calls, since *the example you posted here* is an essentially instantaneous function that wouldn't cause anything to lock up.

Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do and how it would freeze the UI?

If the issue is that you're executing

```
function additem(clientName){
    myListModel.append({name:clientName});
}
```

a thousand times in a tight loop, and that's why your UI is frozen, I can think of a few possible solutions.

One is to periodically call (after every addItem or after every 10 or 20 addItems) the ListView's forceLayout() method — http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#forceLayout-method — which is designed to force an update of the ListView so your UI reflects changes in your model.

That's probably the simplest solution, for this particular case.

For other instances where you might need async functions, you could try using a Timer with a short period (20 ms, say) to execute a subset of tasks and then update your UI (or do whatever), then execute another batch of tasks, and so on.

In some other cases, you might find it useful to use a callback function, i.e., call a function and forget about it, but pass it a callback function to execute when it's done doing its work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I gave an example in Qt Forum, also the **callback** that you explained is what I want, but does callback do that? how do you set the callback that runs async? I tried in javascript but it still waits until callback return it value! here is the Link: https://jsfiddle.net/efvv45aw/

Comment: I don't understand your fiddle. It doesn't actually delay bacon. To run a function and have a callback executed later, you'd do it something like this https://jsfiddle.net/o2ts45dr/

Comment: Also, I assume you're just trying to reason about async with this example, because QML's JavaScript engine doesn't have the setTimeout function, so you wouldn't be able to use it to create callbacks.

Comment: I see... yeah, I'm just trying an example to understand the callback, I mean if callback works in the background, then the bacon function has to come after apple function executed right?, also I think you forgot to save the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably implement the solution using Promise chaining such as:

```
Button {
    text: "Add Names"
    onClicked: {
         appendName("Bill Gates")
         .then( () => sleep(1000) )
         .then( appendName("Steve Jobs") )
         .then( () => sleep(1000) )
         .then( appendName("Jeff Bezos") )
         ;
    }
}
```

In the future, Qt6.6 will have async/await functions. When that happens you should be able to do something like:

```
Button {
    text: "Add Names"
    onClicked: {
         (async function() {
             myListModel.clear();
             myListModel.append({name:"Bill Gates"});
             await sleep(1000);
             myListModel.append({name:"Steve Jobs"});
             await sleep(1000);
             myListModel.append({name:"Jeff Bezos"});
         })();
    }
}
```

In lieu of async/await functions you can use function generators and yield Promises, e.g.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        Label { text: qsTr("Names (count:%1)").arg(myListModel.count) }
        ListView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            clip: true
            model: myListModel
            delegate: Frame {
                id: frame
                width: ListView.view.width
                background: Rectangle {
                    color: index & 1 ? "#e0e0e0" : "#d0d0d0"
                    border.color: "#c0c0c0"
                }
                Text {
                    width: parent.width
                    text: model.name
                }
            }
        }
        Button {
            id: btn
            text: qsTr("Add Names")
            onClicked: {
                (qmlPromises._asyncToGenerator(function*() {
                    btn.enabled = false;
                    myListModel.clear();
                    myListModel.append( { name: "Bill Gates" } );
                    yield sleep(1000);
                    myListModel.append( { name: "Steve Jobs" } );
                    yield sleep(1000);
                    myListModel.append( { name: "Jeff Bezos" } );
                    btn.enabled = true;
                }))();
            }
        }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: myListModel
    }
    Timer {
        id: sleepTimer
        property var resolve
        property var reject
        repeat: false
        running: false
        onTriggered: resolve()
    }
    QMLPromises {
        id: qmlPromises
    }
    function sleep(delay) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            sleepTimer.interval = delay;
            sleepTimer.resolve = resolve;
            sleepTimer.reject = reject;
            sleepTimer.start();
        } );
    }
}

//QMLPromises.qml
import QtQuick
Item {
    function _asyncToGenerator(fn) {
        return function() {
            var self = this,
            args = arguments
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                var gen = fn.apply(self, args)
                function _next(value) {
                    _asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "next", value)
                }
                function _throw(err) {
                    _asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "throw", err)
                }
                _next(undefined)
            })
        }
    }

    function _asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, key, arg) {
        try {
            var info = gen[key](arg)
            var value = info.value
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error)
            return
        }
        if (info.done) {
            resolve(value)
        } else {
            Promise.resolve(value).then(_next, _throw)
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?code=import%20QtQuick%202.15%0Aimport%20QtQuick.Controls%202.15%0Aimport%20QtQuick.Layouts%201.15%0APage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20ColumnLayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20anchors.fill%3A%20parent%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20anchors.margins%3A%2010%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Label%20%7B%20text%3A%20qsTr(%22Names%20(count%3A%251)%22).arg(myListModel.count)%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ListView%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.fillWidth%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.fillHeight%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20clip%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20model%3A%20myListModel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20delegate%3A%20Frame%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20frame%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20width%3A%20ListView.view.width%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20background%3A%20Rectangle%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20index%20%26%201%20%3F%20%22%23e0e0e0%22%20%3A%20%22%23d0d0d0%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20border.color%3A%20%22%23c0c0c0%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Text%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20width%3A%20parent.width%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20model.name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Button%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20btn%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20qsTr(%22Add%20Names%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onClicked%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(qmlPromises._asyncToGenerator(function*()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20btn.enabled%20%3D%20false%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20myListModel.clear()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20myListModel.append(%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22Bill%20Gates%22%20%7D%20)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%20sleep(1000)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20myListModel.append(%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22Steve%20Jobs%22%20%7D%20)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%20sleep(1000)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20myListModel.append(%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22Jeff%20Bezos%22%20%7D%20)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20btn.enabled%20%3D%20true%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D))()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20ListModel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20myListModel%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20Timer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20sleepTimer%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20property%20var%20resolve%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20property%20var%20reject%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20repeat%3A%20false%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20running%3A%20false%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onTriggered%3A%20resolve()%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20QMLPromises%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20qmlPromises%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20sleep(delay)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise(function%20(resolve%2C%20reject)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sleepTimer.interval%20%3D%20delay%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sleepTimer.resolve%20%3D%20resolve%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sleepTimer.reject%20%3D%20reject%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sleepTimer.start()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2FQMLPromises.qml%0Aimport%20QtQuick%0AItem%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20function%20_asyncToGenerator(fn)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20self%20%3D%20this%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20args%20%3D%20arguments%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise(function(resolve%2C%20reject)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20gen%20%3D%20fn.apply(self%2C%20args)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20function%20_next(value)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_asyncGeneratorStep(gen%2C%20resolve%2C%20reject%2C%20_next%2C%20_throw%2C%20%22next%22%2C%20value)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20function%20_throw(err)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_asyncGeneratorStep(gen%2C%20resolve%2C%20reject%2C%20_next%2C%20_throw%2C%20%22throw%22%2C%20err)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_next(undefined)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20function%20_asyncGeneratorStep(gen%2C%20resolve%2C%20reject%2C%20_next%2C%20_throw%2C%20key%2C%20arg)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20try%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20info%20%3D%20gen%5Bkey%5D(arg)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20value%20%3D%20info.value%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20catch%20(error)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reject(error)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(info.done)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(value)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Promise.resolve(value).then(_next%2C%20_throw)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

I recently put together a Qt QML library that encapsulates this:

- https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-promises
- https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-promises-demo

Answer (score -3):

QML has it!
Use `WorkerScript` as explained [here.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qml-workerscript.html) :)
**Update:** Link updated

Comment: Thanks for the comment, as what Jaromandax and folibis suggested, it's one possible solution, but then it raises another problem since it doesn't load QML libraries. I was more looking into the way that can do async the javascript functions rather than running them separately without any libraries but pure Javascript functions.

Comment: to down voters: Whenever an answer has problem or mistake or error, you can explain it within a comment. this will causes to help and make something clear.

Comment: Dear @Bear `WorkerScript` could be used for simple computational operations not running qml in another thread. However you may be able to divide your plugin operations into some computational JS and QML parts. In this case you can migrate computational JS part into a separate thread. If you post a sample code snippet maybe I can help you. Anyway if you need more power and flexibility, you need to go into C++ and `QThread` and show result in GUI thread.

Comment: Hi S.M.Mousavi, thank you for the reply, I'm not very familiar to Multi-threading, honestly I know about it recently, so I'm looking at the example given by Qt documentation, but I'll provide a sample code if I encounter any difficulty, by the way, I can't use C++ for the plugin that I'm developing. the 3rd party application doesn't support c++ library.